# Can I force download mutiple files or a zip file?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm using Cakephp 2.4.

I can actually force download a file (created from string) at each request with the code below:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->body($file);
$this->response->download($log);
$this->response->send();
```

But it's possible to download multiple files in one request? When I put this code in a loop, Cake create one file with the content of the differents files in.

If it's not, is it possible with Cake to create a zip file and put each file in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible, simply because neither the HTTP protocol nor any browser do support something like that, it's not a CakePHP thing.

If you need to serve multiple files with a single request then you'll have to put them in some kind of archive, however that also isn't directly related to CakePHP as it doesn't ship with a ZIP library or similar, it's all about PHP.

I don't think there's any need at this point to explain how to ZIP files with PHP, as this is something that is explained on every corner of the internet.

- **http://php.net/zip**
- **https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+zip**

Once you've zipped your files, either pass the zipped data to `CakeResponse::body()` as a string like you're already doing (not recommended for large archives as it will blow up the memory usage), or temporarily store the ZIP file on disk and use `CakeResponse::file()`.

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files**